# Is there an element similar to angularJs form.firstname.$active in angular 6

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular6

I am looking for an element in angular 6 that is similar finding the active/focused form element so that i can toggle the class on the label related to that input field.

```
<input type="text" money name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" ng-model="amount" />
<label for="amount" ng-class="{'active': form.amount.length || form.amount.$active}">
     Amount to finance
</label>
```

I am trying to do this angular 6, but i can't find an equavalent for $active.

Comment: what does it mean in angular js? Ive never used it before.

Comment: https://angularjs.org/

Comment: can you show your angular 6 code? i think you can achieve it using pure CSS using `:focus` selector

Comment: I have legacy css, i need to achieve this via classes

Answer (score 1):

This is can be partially achieved with directive

HTML

```
    <input type="text" money name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" 
ng-model="amount" appActive/>
    <label for="amount" ng-class="{'active': form.amount.length || form.amount.$active}">
         Amount to finance
    </label>
```

Angular

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appActive]'
})

export class ActiveDirective implements OnChanges {

@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.addActiveClass();
  }

@HostListener('focusin') onFocusIn() {
    console.log('mouseenter1')
  }

  @HostListener('focusout') onFocusOut() {
    console.log('mouseenter2')
  }

  @HostListener('blur') onBlur() {
    this.checkAndRemoveActiveClass();
  }


}
```